# initrd and intramfs purpose confusion

Tags: kernel, drivers, initramfs, root-filesystem, initrd

My understanding of the purpose of having initrd or intramfs is for the kernel to be able to mount  a temporary file system in RAM to load drivers and other things in order to be able to mount the actual rootfs (wherever that may be located).

Having read about this, it seems that the main goal is to be able to maintain a general kernel distribution without hard coding every possible different scenario there to tell how to mount the rootfs during bootup.

I'm guessing the initrd or intramfs is nearly always customized in this case.

However what I don't understand is, don't we still need to modify the kernel code to tell it what to execute when the intramfs is mounted for our specific case? For example, to run a specific script, or even to actually load the drivers and use them etc.

Answer (score 0):

The main point is to save kernel RAM (which is not paged). Rather than building a kernel with everything in it, the kernel is built with some important drivers in it, and the rest available as modules. At boot time the kernel probes the various buses it finds, like pcie, and tries to find modules which claim to be drivers for the various things found. These modules are left in RAM, whilst the rest are discarded. Usually the initrd will contain every possible module, or at least a very large number of them, and the generation of the initrd itself will not involve much customization if any..

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Don't we need to automatically execute some scripts then inside initrd on bootup? Surely we still have to modify the kernel anyways to tell it what to do with the initrd?

Comment: Yes scripts are executed automatically inside the initrd, but they typically are not customized. It is just "probe all the hardware and load the drivers that match". You might have a blacklist of hardware to ignore which you would pass in to the script generating the initrd.